# 'Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.' after merge

Tags: linux, git

I have done the following:

```
git add <filenames>
git commit
git push origin master:mybranch
```

From my origin server, I did the following:

```
git merge mybranch
```

All of my changes are now present on the origin server, however git (and myself) seems incredibly confused now.  When I did a `git status` on the origin, two of the new files I added were present, but listed as untracked files.  However, the modified files are not listed as modified.

When I do a `git status` on my remote server I receive the error **Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.**

When I do a `git diff origin/master` on my remote server all of my changes are listed as not present on the origin server.

What is going on here?

Comment: Your question is incredibly confusing.

'origin' is a remote repository and it's different in different repositories.

For each machine in the question do 'git remote -v' and list the output (with trimmed url's or whatever).

Otherwise it's impossible to figure out what you are saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do a git pull in your master and then merge again
Which branch are you currently on?

usually this is how it goes:

```
git checkout somebranch
*make some changes
git add *any new files here*
git commit -am "commit message"
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git merge somebranch
git push
```

if the master-branch had any changes in it when you pulled you will need to merge those changes over to your working branch.

```
git checkout somebranch
git merge master
```

Comment: you need to checkout to switch from one branch to another. when you make changes in "somebranch" and you want to merge those changes into the "master" branch you first need to switch to the "master" and then merge in what is in "somebranch".. the second checkout is to merge any changes of master into "somebranch" ie if someone else changes something in master while you were working in your "somebranch"

Comment: Also this maybe some good material to read http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Comment: In my remote, I am on the "master" branch, and on the origin i am on the "master" branch.  My understanding is that I am pushing my master branch from the remote to the origin with a particular name when I do `git push origin master:mybranch`.  When I do my `git merge mybranch` on the origin I am assuming I am merging mybranch into the master branch.  Is that not the case?

Comment: when you do a `git merge mybranch` you are merging mybranch into your current branch. so if you are in "master" you will merge "mybranch"s changes into your "master" branch. This means though if there are changes in "master" that are not in "mybranch", those will not move to "mybranch"

Comment: Right.  This is what I am doing.  What I don't understand is, why are my merged changes in the master branch showing up when I do a `git diff origin/master` from my remote server?

Answer (score 0):

you have only pushed the mybranch to your remote. This is why after you merge it into master on the remote you get a "ahead by 1" message. This is not an error.

Do a git fetch and you will have the latest in sync.

Sounds like you don't understand how Git's history structure is built. Google for "git for computer scientists" to get a quick overview, or spend some time reading progit.org/book.